# Can you give examples of interesting properties of the *unary* set union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

By unary set union I mean the unary operation on sets, which for the argument $X$ produces the set $\{y \mid (\exists x) (y \in x \ \& \ x \in X) \}$ customarily denoted as  $\bigcup X$. The unary union differs from the binary union $X \cup Y$ both algebraically (e.g. by arity), and set-theoretically: it may produce a set of a lower rank than the rank of its operand (one can say that the unary union operation may "lower the rank"). This last fact is in contrast with the fact that the binary union produces a set of a rank which equals the highest rank of its arguments  (one can say the  binary union "does not lower the rank"). Recall, the rank of a set is the least ordinal number greater than the rank of any member of the set.

An attractive propery of the unary union is that it can be used in an elegant definition of the notion "transitive set" due to this:

$\bigcup X \subseteq X$ iff $X$ is a transitive set.

There are also two interesting types of sets $X$ defined by each of the formulas $X \subseteq \bigcup X$ and $X = \bigcup X$, but I don't have enough experience with set theory to have encountered them in any theorems and to know names for them.

Anyway, the unary union is a very interesting operation because it sometimes lowers the rank of the set to which it is applied, unlike the widely used binary operations of union, intersection, and difference. Also, this operation is one of a few operations, the existence of the result of application of which is postulated by a ZF axiom, which means this is a very important (maybe, *fundamental*) operation. But I never encountered a paper where the properties of this important operation are explicity formulated.

REMARK. I corrected the body of my question based on the remarks done by @Asaf Karagila and @Andreas Blass.

Comment: The power set operation?

Comment: Union doesn't always lower the rank. For example, the von Neumann ordinal $\omega$ satisfies $\bigcup\omega=\omega$.

Comment: Since Asaf mentioned the power set, I might as well point out a nice connection between $\bigcup$ and $\mathcal P$, namely $X\subseteq\mathcal P(Y)$ if and only if $\bigcup X\subseteq Y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I wonder: (1) whether there is a necessary and sufficient condition (NSC) for a set $X$ to be such that the operation of unary union applied to it does not lower the rank, (2) whether there is a NSC for a set $X$ to satisfy this: $\bigcup X = X$

Comment: Asaf probably mentioned the power set operation to remind that there is yet another operation the existence of the result of application of which is postulated by a ZF axiom. But then, the manner how these two fundamental operations "interact" becomes interesting, and the Andreas' nice connection is an example in this direction.